# Vector Valued Functions, Find some value at point

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose that $r$ is a vector valued function of $t$. Now, $r_0=\langle 2,2,2\rangle$ and $r_1$ is in the $y,z$ plane. If $r' \times \langle 2,3,4\rangle=0 \forall t$, how can I find what $r_1$ is?

I thought that I use matrices to find $r'$, but I can't figure out how to do that, or if that even works.

Comment: Please notice my edit.  That is the correct notation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh ok. I see.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you have any ideas for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
& (r(1)-r(0))\times (1,2,3) = \int_0^1 r'(t)\,dt\times(1,2,3) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 r'(t)\times(1,2,3)\,dt = \int_0^1 (0,0,0)\,dt = (0,0,0).
\end{align}
So
$$
((x,y,0)-(1,1,1))\times(1,2,3) = (0,0,0).
$$
If you now evaluate the cross-product on the left, you get two equations in two variables.

Comment: Is y=-1, z=-2 true?

Comment: $r(1)$ is in the xy plane, not yz plane.

Comment: @user251257 : Sorry, typo.  I've fixed it.

Comment: How do you evaluate this. I'm stuck here again.

Comment: I'm getting $(x-1,y-1,-1)\times(1,2,3) = (3(y-1)+2, -1 - 3(x-1), 2(x-1)-(y-1)).$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** $a\times b = 0$ implies $a$ and $b$ are linearly dependent.

**Hint 2':** Use the mean value theorem, there exists some $0 < c < 1$ such that
$$ r(1) - r(0) = r'(c). $$
It is less restrictive than the fundamental theorem.

**Hint 3:** Exploit $r_z(1) = 0$.

**Solution:**

Since $r'(c)$ and $\langle 1,2,3 \rangle$ are linearly dependent, there is some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ such $r'(c) = \alpha \langle 1,2,3 \rangle$. From $r_z(1) = 0$ and $r_z(1) - r_z(0) = \alpha 3$ we conclude that $\alpha = \frac13$ and thus $r(1) = \langle \frac23, \frac13, 0 \rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I knew that, but what should I do next?

Comment: Hint 2 should do.

Comment: Can you tell me if my answer is correct after I do it. Give me like 10 mins.

Comment: How did you arrive to hint 2?

Comment: It is the Fundamental theorem of calculus. It should be part of each calculus syllabus.

Comment: I just noticed that. But that takes me to 0=0.

Comment: Is the final answer for r(1)=(0,-1,-2)?

Comment: it would, if $r(1)$ was in the yz plane.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be easier to picture if you see the problem physically. Suppose the function describes the motion of a particle; the particle starts at $(1, 1, 1)$ and is moving in the direction of the vector $(1, 2, 3)$ at all times (because its velocity is parallel to this direction) although we don't know what speed it's moving at. That is, the particle is traveling in a straight line.

We're told that at some point, the $z$-coordinate of the particle is $0$. We have
$$
(1, 1, 1) + (s, 2s, 3s) = (?, ?, 0)
$$
Here $s$ is some possibly very complicated function of the time $t$ that we don't know, but it doesn't matter. The third coordinate tells us $s = -1/3$ at the point in question, and so we get $(2/3, 1/3, 0) $ as desired.